# Spring REST: Get JSON data from Request body in addition to entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm working with java project using spring REST.

My problem that i could not extract data from request body (which is json) after receive it as enitiy.

for example:

JSON Request Body

```
{
    "firstname": "Rayan",
    "lastname": "Cold",
    "company_id": 23
}
```

My Controller maaped method is:

```
@PostMapping("/employee")
public Employee createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {

    // Here i need to extract the company id from request body
    // Long companyId = *something* // how i can extract from request ?

    return companiesRepository.findById(companyId).map(company -> {
        employee.setCompany(company);
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Company not found"));
}
```

I know i can pass company ID as path variable. But i do want it in request body not in URI.

Thanks

Comment: give your Employee class in question. I think there is problem in deserialization.

Comment: Post your Employee class code.

Comment: Is company_id part of Employee class?  Can you add Employee.java code also

Comment: @Mohammad Ahmad did u try with my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

company_id can not be mapped if your Employee class contains companyId.

I guess your company class like:

```
public class Employee {

private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private Long companyId;
```

//skip getter setter
    }

change it to :

```
public class Employee {

private String firstname;
private String lastname;
@Transient
@JsonProperty("company_id")
private Long companyId;
```

//skip getter setter
}

Comment: yes also it's working. but it's raise an exception too from Hibernate regarding joining column could not declared twice. You should add @Transient annotation for companyId property. Please update your answer so i could choose it as correct answer.

Comment: added @Transient before id

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take the company id from the object received:

```
employee.getCompany_id();
```

Please ensure, your Employee class should be something like below:

```
public class Employee
{
    private String company_id;

    private String lastname;

    private String firstname;

    // getter and setters of all these member fields

}
```

> Name of the variables should be same as the one in JSON or use the
>   appropriate annotations.

Comment: No i cannot do that, because comapny_id is join column for OneToMany relationship. When you added it as property Hibernate will throw an exception. However if you add @Transient for it. it's works. Please update your answer so i can choose  it as correct answer.